# ISO 3166 code conversion - Alpha to numeric

Tags: converters, iso

I have a situation where I need to convert between ISO 3166 country codes.

For example, using the [ISO 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-3) standard for country codes, `IOT` is the alpha code for `British Indian Ocean Territory` and `086` is it's numeric equivalent.

Another example would be using the [ISO 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217) for currency codes, 'UZS' is the alpha code for `Uzbekistan` and `860` is it's numeric equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You can find machine-processable lists of ISO 3166 country codes in a few places, e.g.:

- in plain text format: http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/countryInfo.txt
- in JSON: https://github.com/mledoze/countries (check the file `countries.json`, which contains much more than just country codes; the README describes its structure).

See also [Full list of ISO ALPHA-2 and ISO ALPHA-3 country codes](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/full-list-of-iso-alpha-2-and-iso-alpha-3-country-codes) on GIS Stack Exchange.

Comment: you can also get a table on wikipedia.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1.  I think I just took that table from the page and put it right into a database table.